# Global Style Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I have the following styles defined in my MainWindow.Resources:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="26"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="358"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="350"/>
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

The TextBlock style is working for TextBlock elements defined inside my MainWindow, but it's not working for the TextBlock used as DataTemplate for my ComboBoxes. Why?

If I set the TextBlock properties inside the element itself, everything works fine:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="26"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock MaxWidth="350" Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="358"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates have a different scope of sorts, you can move the style to the `Application.Resources` which apply even within data and control templates across the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

use dynamic resource

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataSource}">
     <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding}"  />
</DataTemplate>

<ComboBox>
     <ComboBox.Resources>
             <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}" TargetType="TextBox">
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```